# sDNA learn - AIC

Tags: regression, sdna

Is there a way to show the model AIC as output to sDNA learn, in addition to mean GEH and r2? Perhaps by adding a line in sdnaregutilities?

Answer (score 1):

No immediate plans to do this I'm afraid, but it's certainly possible in principle. If you did it on https://github.com/fiftysevendegreesofrad/sdna_open I could accept a pull request.

Comment: Thanks! Would this be something best done in the python scripts? I think sDNA calls R in the background, but I cannot locate the correct R file (I am more familiar with  than python).